# how to call jquery-mobile from android activity

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

i am developing an android app.. in between i want to add mobile jquery..

There is already a jquery project developed by somebody else.
i want to call that html page in my activity..

whether i need to create an webview and call that one?? or can i directly call that html page directly form activity?

And one more thing.. how to add the jquery project in to my project, i mean... in which folder can i place that??
please me help out...

here is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must place the Jquery-Mobile page(+css/scripts) in `assets/www` folder. Then you can call `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`, in any WebView. 
Don't forget to call `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` Make sure you have `INTERNET` permission in the `Manifest` just in case.